# Are global static variables within a file comparable to a local static variable within a function?

Tags: c, variables, static, global

I know declaring a global variable as STATIC will make it visible to the current file. Does the variable retain its data every time functions are called within the file?

For example,

Let's say some file calls func1() below, which modifies the static global variable data and then calls func2() which modifies it again.

The next time a file calls func1(), will it be modifying a new data variable struct? or will it preserve the previous data that was modified in the first call?

```
STATIC MY_DATA  Data1;

void func1( ){
   //modify Data1
   func2(Data1);
}

void func2 (MY_DATA data){
    // modify data 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you test it and find out ;)?

Comment: Never ever (ever ever ever*) ask a software development question when it's easier to try it yourself. You'll learn soooooooo much more doing then you will by asking.

Comment: Note that there is no qualifier `STATIC`.  I presume you are asking about the keyword `static`.

Comment: Huh? How is this question at all opinion based? Perhaps it should be closed, but not for that reason.

Answer (score 6):

The keyword `static` has a different meaning at file scope then it does in a local scope.

At file scope, `static` declares *internal linkage*.  That means only other code in the same translation unit can see the declared variable (or function); if the same name appears in a different file then it designates a separate variable (function).  The opposite is external linkage, which you can declare explicitly via the `extern` keyword.  Additionally, variables declared within a function scope have *no* linkage -- they can be accessed only within the function wherein they are declared.

In a local scope, on the other hand, `static` declares *static storage duration*, as opposed to the default of automatic duration.  Variables with static duration are initialized at program startup and retain their values across function calls, unlike variables with automatic duration.

All variables declared at file scope and all functions have static duration, so although it is potentially confusing, there is no essential ambiguity in using the same keyword for these two distinct purposes in different contexts.

As for your example, whether your file-scope variable is declared `static` or not, it has static storage duration.  Its value will therefore persist across function calls, and all functions in the same file will have access to its current value at all times.  If it is *not* declared `static` then it can be accessed by other functions, too.